# Login in PHP/MYSQL won't go to next page using location

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a *login page* in **php**. If the information is good it should navigate to "**main.php**" and if the information is *false* it should navigate to "**accessdenied.php**". However, the page gets stuck on **checkauth.php**.

So the process is like this:

1. **index.php** <- user enters information and presses login
2. **checkauth.php** <- connects to database and checks the table if information is correct [Gets stuck on this page]
3. should goto either **main.php** or **accessdenied.php** it never gets to either page.

Now to the code

FILENAME: **checkauth.php**

```
    <?php
$username= $_POST['username']; //usernamefrom index.php
$password  = $_POST['password']; //password from index.php

if ($password) 
{
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("Error Connecting To MYSQL Server");
mysql_select_db("DB") or die("Error connecting to database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows != 0) 
{
header( 'location: main.php' ) ;    
}
else 
    header( 'Location: accessdenied.php' ) ;
}
?>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass connection object like

```
mysql_select_db("DB",$connect) or die("Error connecting to database");
```

Answer (score 0):

***MySQL*** is deprecated. Try using ***MySQLi*** instead:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION */

$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","DB");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

/* YOU SHOULD PRACTICE USING MYSQLI_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING TO PREVENT SOME SQL INJECTIONS */

$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']); /* usernamefrom index.php */
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['password']); /* password from index.php */

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query); /* STORE THE TOTAL NUMBER QUERY IN $numrows VARIABLE */

if ($numrows != 0) 
{
header( 'location: main.php' ) ;    
}
else 
    header( 'Location: accessdenied.php' ) ;
}

?>
```